# make url without id in the End in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I have this code for the login process, and the payload in the jwt contains an id and an email
and this is the code :

employeeController:

```
/**
*
* @param req
* @param res
* @return {Promise<*>}
* @private
*/
const _login = async (req, res) => {
      const loginResponse = await EmployeeService.Instance.login(req.body['employee']);
      const responseCode = PCODES.getResponseCode(loginResponse.code);
      res.status(responseCode).json(loginResponse);
};
```

EmployeeServices.js:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} payload to generate token upon
 * @return {Promise<string>} token base64 string
 * @description token will be expired in 10s
 */
static _generateTokenAsync = (payload) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWTSECRETKey,
            {
                expiresIn: 3600
            }, (err, token) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(token);
                }
            });
            console.log(payload);
    });
};


/**
 *
 * @param employee
 * @return {Promise<null|Object>}
 */
async login(employee) {
    if (employee === null || employee === undefined) return {
        message: 'Missing data',
        employee: employee,
        code: PCODES.MISSING_DATA
    };

    const {email, password} = employee;

    if (email === undefined || password === undefined) {
        return {message: 'Missing data', employee: employee, code: PCODES.MISSING_DATA};
    }
    return await EmployeeModel.findOne({
        where: {
            email: email
        },
        include: [
            {
                as: 'EmployeeRoles',
                model: EmployeeRoleModel,
                attributes: ['roleId', 'targetId', 'employeeId'],
                /*through: {
                    model: EmployeeRoleModel,
                    attributes: ['roleId', 'targetId', 'employeeId' ]
                }*/
            }
        ],
        attributes: [
            'id', 'name', 'email', 'password'
        ]
    })
        .then(async (employee) => {
            if (!employee) {
                return {message: 'Employee does not exist', email: email, code: PCODES.FAILED};
            }
            const passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password.toString(), employee.password);
            if (!passwordIsValid) {
                console.log('Password don\'t match');
                return {
                    message: 'Password don\'t match',
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                    code: PCODES.AUTHORIZATION_FAILED
                };
            }
            const token = await EmployeeService._generateTokenAsync({
                id: employee.id,
                email: employee.email
            });
            delete employee['dataValues']['password'];
            employee['dataValues']['token'] = token;
            return {
                message: 'Login successfully', employee: employee, code: PCODES.SUCCESS
            };
        })
        .catch(dbErr => {
            console.log(dbErr);
            return {message: 'Internal server error', code: PCODES.DATABASE_ERROR};
        });
}
```

The question is:
When I want to use the id in another controller, I get it through one of the following :

```
 const employee = res.locals['employee'];  or  const employeeId = req.params['id'];
```

The question is how can I get the id from the token without typing the id used at the end of each url like this url ,this url contains employeeId=14ll0ltgkcc5aycv  :

```
http://localhost:3001/employee/company/14ll0ltgkcc5aycv
```

but I don't want the id to be written at the end of the url. I want to get it from the token and have it uploaded to the payload,How can i do it ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve data from an encoded JWT by verifying/decoding.  Depending on the library, the (server-side) code would look something like:

```js
// get token from request (typically in Authorization header)
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWTSECRETKey);
const employeeId = decoded.EmployeeRoles.employeeId;
```

EDIT:

I'm going to assume you are using the JWT for authentication because you have a login route.  After logging in, the FE client will include the JWT in requests to the server.  Generally, the JWT is included in the Authorization header.

For example:

```sh
curl localhost:3001/employee/company -H "Authorization: Bearer THE_JWT_HERE"
```

The server will parse the Authorization header and verify that the request includes a valid JWT.  Then the server can extract the id from the JWT.

For example:

```js
async function routeLogic(req, res) {
    // Get token from request (structure of req object may differ by framework)
    const token = req.headers.authorization.slice(7); // Remove 'Bearer ' prefix
    // Verify and decode token
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWTSECRETKey);
    // Extract desired key from decoded token
    const employeeId = decoded.id;
    ...
}
```

Retrieving the Authorization header and verifying the JWT is often encapsulated in a plugin/middleware so that it can be easily applied to all desired routes without duplicating code.  What that looks like will depend on which framework you are using.

Comment: Can you explain in detail more?

Comment: @HHHMuhannad I'm assuming you have a FE client that uses the login route to get the JWT.  If the client includes the JWT in subsequent requests to the server, then the server will be able to: (1) retrieve the JWT from the request (2) verify/decode the JWT and (3) access the decoded JWT properties.  Which part would you like more detail on?

Comment: I want the part where I can get an ID from the token and use it in other controllers, there is no difference important to get to my destination, can you explain about the three parts and how to use it in the code ? , and How can i use the id that i get it from token in another controller

Comment: @HHHMuhannad I've added some additional detail to the answer.